# if and statement possible in html files Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I want to create and if/and statement in my code to offer 3 different options for a link.

I've tried the if/else code and it works. Having two if statements (one with the 'AND') will not work because the error states there should be a closing statement after the first 'if'. I've tried using 'elseif' and 'else if' in the second statement, as well, with no luck. Is there a way to do this that I'm not finding?

```
<li class="{% if page.body_class == 'language' %}active{% endif %} hidden-md hidden-lg">
                {% if page.alternate_mx == null %}
                  <a href="/mx/" title="En Español">Español</a>
                {% if page.alternate_mx == null and page.translate_mx %}
                  <a href="/mx/{{page.translate_mx}}" title="En Español">Español</a>
                {% else %}
                  <a href="{{ site.url }}{{site.baseurl}}{{page.alternate_mx}}" title="En Español">Español</a>
                {% endif %}
   </li>
```

- If there is no page.alternate_mx then the first link should appear.
- BUT If there is no page.alternate_mx AND there is a page.translate_mx use the second link.
- If there is a page.alternate_mx use the third link.

I am getting this error: 
"Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 144): 'if' tag was never closed in /usr/src/app/_includes/header/header-en.html, included in /_layouts/default.html
web_1  |              Error: Liquid syntax error (line 144): 'if' tag was never closed
web_1  | ...error:
web_1  |              Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information."

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because you have `if if else endif` there, the first `if` block is not closed. If `elsif` is not working for you, you can try to rearrange statements like so:

```
<li class="{% if page.body_class == 'language' %}active{% endif %} hidden-md hidden-lg">
        {% if page.alternate_mx == null %}
            {% if page.translate_mx %}
                <a href="/mx/{{page.translate_mx}}" title="En Español">Español</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="/mx/" title="En Español">Español</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
          <a href="{{ site.url }}{{site.baseurl}}{{page.alternate_mx}}" title="En Español">Español</a>
        {% endif %}
</li>
```

Also you probably should use `&&` instead of `and` because they have different precedence.

```
<li class="{% if page.body_class == 'language' %}active{% endif %} hidden-md hidden-lg">
                {% if page.alternate_mx == null %}
                  <a href="/mx/" title="En Español">Español</a>
                {% elsif page.alternate_mx == null && page.translate_mx %}
                  <a href="/mx/{{page.translate_mx}}" title="En Español">Español</a>
                {% else %}
                  <a href="{{ site.url }}{{site.baseurl}}{{page.alternate_mx}}" title="En Español">Español</a>
                {% endif %}
   </li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about && and it always helps to have a second set of eyes for those errors.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this and it worked great.

````
<li class="{% if page.body_class == 'language' %}active{% endif %} hidden-md hidden-lg">

{% if page.translate_mx %}
          <a href="{{page.translate_mx}}" title="En Español">Español</a>
    {% elsif page.alternate_mx == null %}
           <a href="/mx/" title="En Español">Español</a>
    {% else %}
          <a href="{{page.alternate_mx}}" title="En Español">Español</a>
 {% endif %}

</li>```
````